# Why does android studio default use Gradle 2.14.1 instead of latest?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I notice that the lastest Gradle version is 3.1, however, the latest Android Studio only ship with Gradle 2.14. So why not use the newest Gradle version?

Answer (score 0):

as of any builder, or app they probably are waiting for feedback from the users, and are putting the new grade under sort of unofficial beta phase.